# Low coupling and tight cohesion

Tags: c++, coupling

Of course it depends on the situation. But when a lower level object or system communicate with an higher level system, should callbacks or events be preferred to keeping a pointer to the higher level object?

For example, if we are working on a game, we have a `world class` that has a member variable `vector<monster> monsters`. When the `monster class` is going to communicate with the `world class`, should I prefer using a callback function then or should I have a pointer to the world class inside the monster class?

Comment: Is the world object a single instance? If so, you may want you use the Singleton pattern.

Comment: You probably don't want a Singleton if low coupling is a concern.  Singletons allow coupling from all over the place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It generally is preferrable to use callbacks to communicate with higher level classes for the reasons you mention and to avoid mutual/cyclic dependencies.

In your case, you still have to define what is the lower level module.  Should world really need to know what a monster is?  Aren't monster just creatures or opponenents? Doesn't monster need some kind of environment to act in?  Only you can answer that to come to a workable solution.

Comment: yes monsters are just creatures, but the question was more general if I should use pointers or callbacks, what is the best solution.

Comment: @hidayat: that was the first (and main) part of the answer.  I just wanted to point out that it is not always obvious what the higher class should be.